# Where does gitlab-runner download job artifacts zip file?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have build, test and deploy jobs in gitlab-ci file. The artifact created at the test job and should be passed to deploy job. I see that the artifacts downloading in the console (See the image) but I can't find it at the specified path. So where does the gitlab-runner save the artifacts. How to use them in subsequent jobs?

The deploy job is dependent upon test job via dependencies tag.[image showing artifacts downloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiigN.png)

Comment: Would be useful to see your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file as well, but when using artifacts you should have set a `path`. The job using the artifacts would see the files in exactly the same place as the path you specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifacts are downloaded to your build main directory, the same directory that your code is being cloned to